# different definition of compound symmetry in SAS

Tags: mixed-model, covariance, sas

I have two questions about the covariance structure in SAS (PROC MIXED).

1. I realize the compound symmetry structure in SAS allows the covariance term to be negative.  This is different from the literature where the covariance is always positive so it is equivalent to a random intercept model. Why does SAS define it differently? I can hardly imagine a situation where the repeated measures are mutually negatively correlated. Is this even possible?
2. I don't understand the default variance components structure. see [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect019.htm).  Why are the first two variances equal to $\sigma^2_B$ and the second two equal to $\sigma^2_{AB}$? What do the subscripts $B$ and $AB$ represent?

Comment: Could you provide your SAS code? I have seen if you run a random slope model (instead of random intercept) and impose a compound symmetry structure, SAS may replace that by an unstructured covariance matrix regardless of what you impose, therefore, allowing the covariances to be negative. However, I have never seen SAS returning negative covariances for a random intercept model if the covariance structure is compound symmetry. For example, this one below returns a covariance matrix with compound symmetry structure. `proc mixed data= import method=ml covtest; class ID ; model DV= TIME /solution

Answer (score 3):

My two cents (more familiar with R than SAS); compound symmetry with $\rho<0$ is useful in cases where there is some compensation within groups, e.g. individuals who do worse than average on some machines do better than average on others, or some resource is being divided among individuals in a group.  Technically, it's useful for cases where the among-group variance would otherwise be estimated as negative ...

Comment: When I learned about this, weights of animals in a litter were one of the examples: there's a total resource constraint that implies negative correlations within a litter.   I don't think we saw *data*, though.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the VC structure, it has as many parameters as random effects. That structure specifies that the random effects are uncorrelated and that each has its own variance. The covariance matrix is thus diagonal, with element $i$ given by $\sigma_k^2$ and $i$ corresponding to the $k$th effect.